# The 'get' equivalent of _set_se_translator?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, seh, structured-exception

I need to translate structured exceptions manually, using the current translator.

How do I 'get' the value someone has set by `_set_se_translator`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Better (new) way

I didn't realize this at first, but the SE translator is **thread-local**, *not* process-wide.

So this is actually the best (and easiest) solution:

```
_se_translator_function _get_se_translator(void) {
    _se_translator_function translator = _set_se_translator(NULL);  // temporary
    _set_se_translator(translator);  // Restore the old value
    return translator;
}
```

#### Hacky (old) way

There is no direct way to do this, but if you're going to risk some incompatibility and delve into the Visual C runtime's internals, you can hack up a solution like this:

```
_se_translator_function __cdecl _get_se_translator(void) {
    unsigned char const *p = (unsigned char const *)(&__uncaught_exception);
    struct _tiddata {
        unsigned long _tid;
        void *_thandle;
        int _terrno; unsigned long _tdoserrno;
        unsigned int _fpds;
        unsigned long _holdrand;
        char *_token; wchar_t *_wtoken;
        unsigned char *_mtoken;
        char *_errmsg; wchar_t *_werrmsg;
        char *_namebuf0; wchar_t *_wnamebuf0;
        char *_namebuf1; wchar_t *_wnamebuf1;
        char *_asctimebuf; wchar_t *_wasctimebuf;
        void *_gmtimebuf;
        char *_cvtbuf;
        unsigned char _con_ch_buf[5];
        unsigned short _ch_buf_used;
        void *_initaddr; void *_initarg;
        void *_pxcptacttab;
        void *_tpxcptinfoptrs;
        int _tfpecode;
        void *ptmbcinfo; void *ptlocinfo;
        int _ownlocale;
        unsigned long _NLG_dwCode;
        void *_terminate; void *_unexpected;
        _se_translator_function _translator;
    };
    if (p[0] == 0x48) /* sub RSP, 0x28 */ { p += 4; }  // x64 only
    if (p[0] == 0xE8) /* call _getpid */ { ++p; }  // must be true
    void const *_getptd = p + *(long *)p + sizeof(long);
    return ((struct _tiddata *(__cdecl *)(void))_getptd)()->_translator;
}
```

Comment: The hacky way almost gave me a heart attack.  The new way is better, though it is within the realm of possibility that an exception could be thrown from another thread between the two calls to _set_se_translator :)

Comment: @Luke: lol. How do you throw an exception from another thread?

Comment: Doh, didn't see the part about the handler being maintained per-thread.